# Error: "requestFeature() must be called before adding content", although it is called before setContentView()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I have an Activity which uses the ActionBarSherlock. Now I wanted to show an Indeterminate Progress in that actionbar and followed the example from ActionBarSherlock:

```
public class MainMenu extends SimpleWebActivity implements BackgroundBrowserReciever {
    private Boolean windowFeatureCalled;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.windowFeatureCalled = true;
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
                ....
    }
```

The SimpleWebActivity is an abstract class which extends a SherlockActivity.

But when I try to load that Activity, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dalthed.tucan/com.dalthed.tucan.ui.MainMenu}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Why does this error occur, even when i request that WindowFeature before calling setContentView?

Answer (score 5):

Move it after your Super.onCreate, that should resolve your issue.

```
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//HERE
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

            setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
  this.windowFeatureCalled = true;
                    ....
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you check the latest of my edits, haha, i had a malfunction :P

Comment: This saved me from crash. Still ActionBarSpinner Dosent Apper. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this  it works for me

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//HERE
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

         this.windowFeatureCalled = true;
                ....
    }
```