# Android requestFeature() must be called, NOT a Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

First of all let me apologize, this is a long post with a wall of code, but I wanted to be thorough.

I get an error in my `logcat` when I click the button to start this `fragment` in my program. It's stating I must "*requestFeature() before adding content*". I've exhausted all resources on these forums. I went through all 16 posts on the subject but here are a few just to show you.

[error: requestFeature() must be called before adding content - Still won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568479/error-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content-still-wont-work)

["android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content" on showDialog(dialogId)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826407/android-util-androidruntimeexception-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-ad)

[Dialog problem: requestFeature() must be called before adding content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661459/dialog-problem-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content)

[Error: "requestFeature() must be called before adding content", although it is called before setContentView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839414/error-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content-although-it-is-c)

None of these solutions worked

The recurring theme with these posts seems to be a problem with `dialogs`, `custom`, `action`, etc. My error occurs when trying to launch a `fragment` that captures signatures. Similar but not that same.

So here is my code and my logcat.

**fragment**

```
public class CaptureSignature extends Fragment {

private static final Context Context = null;
View view;
LinearLayout mContent;
signature mSignature;
Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
public static String tempDir;
public int count = 1;
public String current = null;   
View mView;
File mypath;

private String uniqueId;
private EditText yourName;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signature, container, false); 

    mClear = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    yourName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.yourName);

    uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_"
            + Math.random();
    current = uniqueId + ".png";

    mContent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(Context, null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);     
    mView = mContent;       

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            boolean error = captureSignature();
            if (!error) {
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                                         
            }
        }
    });

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");                         
        }
    });
    return view;

}   

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
    super.onDestroy();
}

private boolean captureSignature() {

    boolean error = false;
    String errorMessage = "";

    if (yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
        error = true;
    }

    if (error) {
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(Context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
        toast.show();
    }

    return error;
}

private String getTodaysDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int todaysDate = (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000)
            + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100)
            + (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Log.w("DATE:", String.valueOf(todaysDate));
    return (String.valueOf(todaysDate));

}

private String getCurrentTime() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentTime = (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000)
            + (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) + (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.w("TIME:", String.valueOf(currentTime));
    return (String.valueOf(currentTime));

}       

public class signature extends View {
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context captureSignature, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(captureSignature, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }



    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        default:
            debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string) {
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
}
```

**Main Activity Code**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

TabListener<Store_Fragment> surveyTabListener;  
TabListener<Store_Fragment> assetTabListener;
TabListener<Store_Fragment> installTabListener;
TabListener<Store_Fragment> punchTabListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    // instantiate ActionBar
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable((getResources()
    //.getDrawable(R.drawable.titlebarheader)));
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setTitle("Trakflex");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // set surveyTab
    Tab surveyTab = actionBar.newTab();
    surveyTabListener = new TabListener<Store_Fragment>(this,
            R.id.header_fragment_container, Store_Fragment.class);      
    surveyTab.setText("Survey").setContentDescription("Survey Tab")
            .setTabListener(surveyTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(surveyTab);

    // set assetTab
    Tab assetTab = actionBar.newTab();
    assetTabListener = new TabListener<Store_Fragment>(this,
            R.id.header_fragment_container, Store_Fragment.class);
    assetTab.setText("Assets").setContentDescription("Assets Tab")
            .setTabListener(assetTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(assetTab);

    // set installTab
    Tab installTab = actionBar.newTab();
    installTabListener = new TabListener<Store_Fragment>(this,
            R.id.header_fragment_container, Store_Fragment.class);
    installTab.setText("Install Checklist")
            .setContentDescription("Install Checklist Tab")
            .setTabListener(installTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(installTab);

    // set punchTab
    Tab punchTab = actionBar.newTab();
    punchTabListener = new TabListener<Store_Fragment>(this,
            R.id.header_fragment_container, Store_Fragment.class);
    punchTab.setText("Punchlist").setContentDescription("Punchlist Tab")
            .setTabListener(punchTabListener);
    actionBar.addTab(punchTab);

}
```

**new logcat**

```
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex/com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Main.onCreate(Main.java:32)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-13 18:57:19.767: E/AndroidRuntime(8950):     ... 11 more
```

If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `requestWindowFeature()` from `onCreateView()` of a `Fragment`. This is entirely too late. As the error says, `requestFeature() must be called before adding content`. Here, "adding content" refers to things like `setContentView()` on your activity or running a `FragmentTransaction`, both of which will have occurred before `onCreateView()` of your `Fragment` will be called.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, I know I can trust that you have a very good understanding of this problem. So may I ask then, when/where should I call the requestWindowFeature()? In my Main Activity/ParentActivity?

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: "when/where should I call the requestWindowFeature()?" -- as the very first statement in your `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. I've even seen it called before `super.onCreate()`, particularly if the superclass will itself by handling the content view (e.g., `ListActivity`).

Comment: hm, well I've attempted to put it in my `Activity`. Before the `super` after the `super` but before the `view` is inflated. They all crash my program on start now. I now have a `NullPointerException` error. **sigh**. I am exhausted from this problem and my utter lack of understanding

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: Usually, you specify that you want no title bar via your theme (e.g., `Theme.Holo.NoTitleBar`). I am not quite certain why you are doing it in Java. That being said, fresh code and a fresh stack trace would certainly help us in pointing out the source of your `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You're right, I should just define it there. I might try it afterwards but at this point I am determined to try and get this working (however futile it may be). I updated my post

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: Ummm... you are trying to work with the action bar, after having said you don't want the action bar. `FEATURE_NO_TITLE` on API Level 11+ gets rid of the action bar, as there is no title bar. Your `NullPointerException` is probably the `ActionBar` object itself -- whatever line 32 is.

Comment: *facepalm*, this is why borrowing code never works. The root of all this evil was copy paste and not understanding the code first. I simply wanted to add a signature capture fragment to my application and it has ruined everything! haha, no but seriously. I think I just have to take this fragment out as I completely lack the understanding needed of what the code is doing

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: I'm not aware of an existing reusable signature capture library that you could use. If nobody beats me to it, I'll write one myself later this year.

Comment: thanks for being so kind to me and trying to figure out why this wasn't working. In the end I feel that whole line is useless because it's simply trying to request the window to strip the title. Yet when I pull it out I get more errors. I'm gonna take a break and come back to this problem. One last question, can you explain why that line would be needed at all for the fragment code?

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: It shouldn't be required at all, barring a really bizarrely written fragment. Where are you getting this fragment from?

Comment: Here is where I got this code, I removed all the save features and junk that I felt I didn't need. Obviously I didn't understand it well enough to tinker with it though http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-capture-signature-using-canvas.html

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: Well, that's an activity, not a fragment. It's also not exactly what I'd consider *primo* Android code. It's not even really "signature capture", but more of a hunk of fingerpaint code, and you can probably find something better for fingerpaint, such as the one in the SDK samples. That being said, at a quick glance I don't see how leaving the title/action bar alone would cause any particular problems. But, this is one of the reasons why creating a real signature capture `View`/`Fragment` is on my to-do list.

Comment: Ya you're 100% correct with that analogy of "fingerpaint activity" I was trying to manipulate the code into working as a `fragment` rather than an `activity` and obviously I've failed. I will attempt to look for better code to use an example. Thanks for all you're time and help